# Using forceRootUrl() breaks some routing

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have my Laravel app running from a subdirectory, so in order to be able to use the URL helper like this: `{{ url('users') }}` instead of like this `{{ url('subdirectory/users') }}` I use the `forceRouteUrl()` method in my AppServiceProvider.php file. It looks like this:

```
public function boot()
    {
        URL::forceRootUrl(Config::get('app.url'));

...
```

And my .env: `APP_URL=http://app.dev/subdirectory`

So far so good, except when returning routes. For example I have a sorting method that does this:

```
function sort_schedule($column, $order)
{
    return route('schedule', [
                 'sortBy' => $column,
                 'sortOrder' => $order,
            ]
         );
}
```

But the link it generates is this: `http://app.dev/subdirectory/subdirectory/...`

The same thing happens when I use [Kyslik's Column Sortable](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable) package.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that while other helpers like url() or asset() don't have this issue, the route() helper tends to duplicate the subpath when laravel isn't accessible directly from the site root and forceRootUrl() is used.
I'm using laravel 5.4 but this problem is present on previous versions too.

To solve this issue i found three possible solutions:

1. Use url() instead of route() and manually create your urls
2. Everytime you use route() remember to pass false as the third parameter, it will use relative paths that don't have this issue
3. Override the default route() helper with a custom one

I opted for the third option and created a CustomHelper.php file that contains my new route() helper.
Here are the instructions on how to override default helpers:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/override-functions-in-supporthelpersphp

Inside my CustomHelper.php file I added this

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
{
    $appUrl = config('app.url'); // in your case: http://app.dev
    $appUrlSuffix = config('app.url_suffix'); // in your case: subdirectory

    // Additional check, do the workaround only when a suffix is present and only when urls are absolute
    if ($appUrlSuffix && $absolute) {
        // Add the relative path to the app root url
        $relativePath = app('url')->route($name, $parameters, false);
        $url = $appUrl.$relativePath;
    } else {
        // This is the default behavior of route() you can find in laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php
        $url = app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }

    return $url;
}
```

The app.url_suffix is a custom variable that i defined in config/app.php

```
'url_suffix' => env('APP_URL_SUFFIX', null),
```

and in the .env config file

```
APP_URL_SUFFIX=subdirectory
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that you have to include the CustomHelper.php file inside bootstrap/autoload.php. Add require __DIR__ . '/../app/Http/CustomHelpers.php'; before the inclusion of the vendor autoload.php